# Issues publishing my stored procedure to azure - The data types time and datetime are incompatible in the add operator

Tags: sql, azure, stored-procedures

I am trying to publish my app to azure, but I got the error below

> The data types time and datetime are incompatible in the add operator.

This is strange because on my computer my app works perfectly fine no error messages related to the date datetime operator.

my stored procedure is below,
Any help to find the issue will be greatly appreciate.
Thanks...!!!

```
    @Tenant int, @UnitId int
AS

DECLARE @LeaseExp as Date
DECLARE @Address as nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @Address1 as nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @SubjectLeaseExpire as nvarchar(255)

DECLARE @TIMESTART TIME = '09:00:00'
DECLARE @TIMEEND TIME = '09:15:00'
DECLARE @DATETIMEstart DATETIME
DECLARE @DATETIMEend DATETIME  


Begin
SELECT      @LeaseExp = Lease.LEAEnd, @Address = Units.UNIAddress, @Address1 = Units.UNIAddress1
FROM          Lease 
INNER JOIN Units ON Lease.LEAUnitId = Units.UNIId

WHERE         Lease.LEAUnitId = @UnitId and Lease.LEAId = @Tenant

DECLARE @DATETIME DATETIME = @LeaseExp

SET @DATETIMEstart = @TIMESTART+@DATETIME
SET @DATETIMEEND = @TIMEEND+@DATETIME

SET @SubjectLeaseExpire ='Lease will not be renewed modify Occupancy on the Unit: '+ @Address + @Address1 +' and Terminate Tenant in the system'

insert into Calendar(Start, Finish, Subject)
Values (@DATETIMEstart, @DATETIMEEND, @SubjectLeaseExpire)

End
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure even if it's working in your local machine, but definitely

the issue is in these two lines :

```
SET @DATETIMEstart = @TIMESTART+@DATETIME
SET @DATETIMEEND = @TIMEEND+@DATETIME
```

see fiddle , for sure its failing : *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ef18774d359e7347ea09c801f1eb7592)*

instead  you can need to cast them both to datetime and add them together like so:

```
SET @DATETIMEstart  = @DATETIME + CAST(@TIMESTART AS DATETIME);
```

and the same for @DATETIMEEND,

Comment: Thanks for your answer I agree with you regarding the issue should be in these two lines, because are the only ones that have the operator, but if that is the case what will be the right way to do it.